# Compact way of storing one-way friend relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a mysql database. I have a table of users. I want to answer the question of "is one user a friend of another?". These are one-way friend relationships. I think I have two options, and want the more performant solution:

1) Keep a table of friend relationships. Two columns:

```
username | friend_username
--------------------------
 mary        john
 mary        steve
 mary        kate
 ...
```

Answering the question of friendship is just selecting the count where the two columns match username 1 & 2.

2) A table with two columns again:

```
username | friends_serialized
-----------------------------
mary       john,steve,kate,
```

So the "friends_serialized" column holds a (comma) delimited string. If I want to know if mary is friends with someone, I can do:

```
select count from xxx where username="mary" AND friends_serialized LIKE "%,steve,%"
```

(I'm not sure of the syntax). Would that really win me anything over the first implementation? It's at least more compact, and when I need to deliver a list of friends to a user, I can get it in a single column read instead of selecting all matching columns (as in #1).

My problem: I'm running a game service where users can send invites to one another to play a game. I want to prevent strangers from sending non-friends invites. So I want to be able to quickly (and compactly) find out if a user sending an invite to another user is actually a mutual friend.

Thanks

Comment: the second one might be a little tough editing friends, such as removing friends with same first names,

Comment: this migh be usefull to store the id of the friends in the databse and check in those id. if the freind id found that true

Answer (score 3):

You should *absolutely* go with the first approach. Your second approach violates even First Normal Form for relational databases (not storing more than one value (in this case a friendship) in a single field.

Answer (score 0):

The first one you mentioned is the best answer.because in the second one after getting the string you have to analyze it to find about friends but the first one is more direct!

Answer (score 0):

Use IDs not strings.

Create a junction Table:

```
ID  PersonID FriendID
0    1        2
1    4        2
2    2        3
.....
```

Person 2 is a friend of both person 1 and 4.
Person 3 is a friend of person 2.

Comment: There's no reason that an ID (I'm assuming by that you mean *key*, specifically *primary key*) cannot be a string. If `username` is stable, not nullable, and unique, there's no need to create a surrogate key.

Comment: Best practices use binary IDs/Keys.  They are faster and when people get married and their names changes, you don't have an update nightmare.  However, strings will work.

Comment: Yes, and there's absolutely no reason that a string cannot be a key.

Comment: If the name changes, it is (by definition) not stable. However, items like usernames are almost always stable (people don't change their usernames, which are often pseudonyms, when they get married, for example), non-nullable (everyone must have one), and unique (they are used to uniquely identify a user already). There are many things to consider when choosing a primary key that way well lead you away from using a particular string field as the primary key, but a blanket "MUST ALWAYS ADD IDENTITY COLUMN" approach is not wise.

Comment: Blanket rules are generally bad, but it's often best to design with the most flexibility in mind, and to take the context into account. In business environments, for instance, usernames are often simply based on the real name (<first initial><last name> is quite common). While employees don't always request username changes when they get married, I'll bet many DO request them when they get divorced.

However, using a username->ID table means an extra join on many queries when the input is a username.

Comment: @Barmar  "Blanket rules are generally bad,"   Where you trying to be ironic?  You made a blanket rule about blanket rules.

Comment: No, it would have been truly ironic if I'd said "blanket rules are always bad".

Comment: Point taken.  BTW:  I didn't make a blanket rule.  I used the phrase "Best Practice".  Like, it's a best practice to check the return values of functions.  It's a best practice to wrap database activity in an exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the first solution. Create a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE friendships (
   user varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   friend varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (user, friend)
   FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES users (user_name) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (friend) REFERENCES users (user_name)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

That will give insure that a row can not be inserted into the `friendships` table if both usernames (`user` and `friend`) do not exist in your `users` table. Also, if you delete a user, all their friendships are delete. Same with updated a username (if you allow it). Plus, since then friendships are one-way and a given user can only be friends with another user one time, it will suffice to make both columns your `PRIMARY KEY`.

Then, it's a very simple query to find a given users friends:

`SELECT friend FROM friendships WHERE user='username'`

Comment: `on delete cascade` - I don't like the sound of that. I don't think you should encourage the concept of a changing primary key.

Comment: If you don't like the sound of delete cascades, you don't understand them.  They are very useful at preventing orphan records.  Even when the database is being edited with a tool.